# How to get Terraform endpoint_resource_id from azurerm_storage_account

Tags: azure, terraform

You want to set private_link_access on azurerm_storage_account.

1. 1. private_link_access : "/subscriptions/00000-00000-00000-00000/providers/Microsoft.Security/datascanners/storageDataScanner"

Is there any way to get endpoint_resource_id by data source or other means without specifying endpoint_resource_id explicitly as shown below?

- main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
  name                              = var.azstorageaccount_name
  resource_group_name               = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  location                          = var.location
  account_tier                      = var.account_tier             # Premium, Standard
  account_replication_type          = var.account_replication_type # GRS
  account_kind                      = var.account_kind             # FileStorage
  access_tier                       = var.access_tier              # Hot, Cool
  large_file_share_enabled          = var.large_file_share_enabled
  is_hns_enabled                    = var.is_hns_enabled
  sftp_enabled                      = var.is_sftp_enabled
  public_network_access_enabled     = var.public_network_access_enabled

  blob_properties  {
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = var.container_delete_retention_policy
    }
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = var.delete_retention_policy
    }
  }
  
  network_rules {
    default_action             = var.network_rules_default_action
    ip_rules                   = toset("${var.network_rules_ip_rules}")
    private_link_access {
      endpoint_resource_id = "/subscriptions/00000-00000-00000-00000/providers/Microsoft.Security/datascanners/storageDataScanner"
    }
    # virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.network_subnet.id]
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.tag}"
  }
}
```

- var.tf

```
variable "azstorageaccount_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "teststroage001"
}

variable "large_file_share_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "account_tier" {
  type    = string
  default = "Standard"
}

variable "account_replication_type" {
  type    = string
  default = "LRS"
}

variable "account_kind" {
  type    = string
  default = "BlobStorage"
}

variable "access_tier" {
  type    = string
  default = "Cool"
}

variable "is_hns_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "is_sftp_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "public_network_access_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "true"
}

variable "container_delete_retention_policy" {
  type    = string
  default = "7"
}

variable "delete_retention_policy" {
  type    = string
  default = "7"
}

variable "network_rules_default_action" {
  type = string
  default = "Deny" # Allow
}

variable "network_rules_ip_rules" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [ " ]
}

variable "endpoint_resource_id" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}
```

Comment: Maybe using this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/private_link_service?

Comment: It is not private_link_service, but private_link_access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try dynamic block:

main.tf

```
dynamic "private_link_access" {
  endpoint_resource_id = private_link_access.value.endpoint_resource_id
}
```